# jQuery Selectors: Capturing A Links

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I think I'm having a problem with my selector.  I have an rotating carousel and wish to capture all of the `a` clicks inside of the `li` (each `li` contains a clickable background image and links).

I'm pretty sure my selector is correct up to the `li` since I can replace the `a` and the `.click` event with `.hide()` and it hides the 2nd image (`li`) correctly.  How do I correct my selector to capature all of the `a` links?

```
jQuery('#flexgrid .columns div ul#rotator-slides.slides li:eq(1) a').click(function(event){    
  event.preventDefault();  
  alert('got it'); 
});
```

Thanks 
(Edit:  Added code 1st li only; the next 4 follow the same format if that helps)

```
<div id="flexgrid">
  <div class="columns"> 
    <div class="flexslider col-reset" id="standard-rotator" data-slide-speed="9500" data-animation-speed="900">
      <ul class="slides" id="rotator-slides">
        <li class="rotator-slide item" data-slide="1">
          <div class="mboxDefault">
            <div class="text-block">
              <div class="hero-content" style="left: 10px; top: 70px;">
                <div class="position-content">
                  <div class="button-bottom" style="width: 360px;">
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
                    <p><em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </em></p>
                  </div>
                  <a href="storefront.html" target="_self" class="button">Find Out More </a> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="storefront.html" target="_self" class="hero-image" style="background-image:url(/images/hero1.jpg);"></a> 
          </div>
          <script>mboxCreate('carousel-slide-1');</script> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't tell without the HTML - post zeh source! Also, you could shorten that selector to just start at the element with an ID - seeing as how all your ID's *should* be unique.

Comment: So, you want to capture all `a` within `li`?

Comment: We are using DOM manipulation (Test & Target) to change the display so we don't have access to the source code to implement IDs throughout the page.  Amit, yes - but for that li only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the a elements are generated by the carousel plugin, you need to use jQuery's "live" function: https://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$( "#flexgrid .columns div ul#rotator-slides.slides li:eq(1) a" ).live( "click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    alert('got it'); 
  });
});
```

**//edit:**
As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().
So it should be:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#flexgrid ul#rotator-slides li:eq(0)" ).on( "click", "a", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    alert('got it'); 
  });
});
```

Comment: TheCutter,  I was just going to note live had been depreciated, so thanks for the edit.  Unfortunately, it's not working.  The alert is not fired and the link executes.

Comment: Ok, normally it should work with live/on. Would be easier to have the HTML code...

Comment: Which jQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.10

Comment: Sorry there was a syntax error in the script. Please see the edit above. Also the li:eq(1) should be li:eq(0) to select the first li element. - I got it working with this lines of javascript.

Comment: TheCutter - thanks for continuing to help me out here.  I get an error when clicking (per Firebug) that the event is not defined.  If this is working locally for you, where should I start looking to get to the cause of this error?

ReferenceError: event is not defined
event.preventDefault();

Comment: I'm sry, copying official documentation code and mixing this with custom code without testing is not a good idea. Just have a look at the edit above. The "event" parameter in the function callback was missing.